# javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host?

Tags: java, email, servlets

following is my code to send mail:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Message.RecipientType;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
public class SendMail {
    public void sendMail(String m_from,String m_to,String m_subject,String m_body){
      try {
            Session m_Session;
            Message m_simpleMessage;
            InternetAddress m_fromAddress;
            InternetAddress m_toAddress;
            Properties m_properties;

            m_properties     = new Properties();
            m_properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "usdc2spam2.slingmedia.com"); 
            m_properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
            m_properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            m_properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            m_properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "9000");

            m_Session=Session.getDefaultInstance(m_properties,new Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("aaaaa","bbbbb@1"); // username and the password
                }
            });

            m_simpleMessage  =   new MimeMessage(m_Session);
            m_fromAddress    =   new InternetAddress(m_from);
            m_toAddress      =   new InternetAddress(m_to);

            m_simpleMessage.setFrom(m_fromAddress);
            m_simpleMessage.setRecipient(RecipientType.TO, m_toAddress);
            m_simpleMessage.setSubject(m_subject);

            m_simpleMessage.setContent(m_body, "text/html");

            //m_simpleMessage.setContent(m_body,"text/plain");

            Transport.send(m_simpleMessage);
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      SendMail send_mail    =   new SendMail();
      String empName = "xxxxx";
      String title ="<b>Hi !"+empName+"</b>";
      send_mail.sendMail("123erft@slingmedia.com", "abz@gmail.com", "Please apply for leave for the following dates", title+"<br>by<br><b>HR<b>");
    }
}
```

but when i run the  code it gives me the following exception.

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: usdc2spam2.slingmedia.com, port: 9000;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1934)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at samples.SendMail.sendMail(SendMail.java:46)
    at samples.SendMail.main(SendMail.java:55)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:288)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:231)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1900)
```

when i ping this `usdc2spam2.slingmedia.com` it gives me reply without any problem. I am using `windows 7`

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: ping is not a proof that you can send an email. Try `telnet usdc2spam2.slingmedia.com 9000`. Or if you (Win7) don't have `telnet`, use e.g. [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)

Comment: What happens when you try `telnet usdc2spam2.slingmedia.com 9000`?  I suspect that you're specifying the wrong port in the `mail.smtp.port` property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is these two lines which was casting me the problem :

```
m_properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
  m_properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
```

and added this line :

```
m_properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
```

After removing and adding the above lines of code it worked fine.

Comment: should explain why this line is not needed

Answer (score 4):

What causes your problem is right there in the stack trace:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

do you need a password to connect to the SMTP server? Are you sure you are using the right settings (as in port number)? Are you behind a proxy or a firewall? Can you use those settings in a regular mail program (e.g. Thunderbird) and send mails?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add port 9000 to your inbound rules in your windows firewall.

Answer (score 2):

This exception usually occurs when there is no service listening on the port you are trying to connect to.

Try to connect using `putty` or `telnet`. I can bet you will get the same error.

Verify these things:

- Host name and port you're trying to connect to,
- The server is listening correctly, and
- There's no firewall blocking the connection.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
```

This might work

Comment: Exactly this code snippet will not work in the OPs code for sure, so please add some explaining text or just list the properties with their respective settings or adapt the code so it can be easily used in the OPs provided code.